# onClick / onItemClick JSX Syntax React + Office UI Fabric

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, jsx, onitemclick

```
          <div>
            <CommandBar 
            areNamesVisible={false} areIconsVisible={true}
            items={[
            { name:"James Towns", className:"noHoverEffect", },
            { key:"Info", icon:"Contact", onItemClick={this.handlePanel} },
            { key:"Export", icon:"Download" }
            ]}       />
          </div>
```

I am using the component `CommandBar` from Office UI Fabric and I've created the contents as desired as shown in the attached image:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve next is attach an `onClick` or `onItemClick` to one of the Items.

Not sure how this works entirely and the JSX syntax doesn't seem to be straight forward.

My function is *handlePanel*  any help appreciated, looked up and down the web for a few days couldn't find a pre-existing question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind you function name in constructor or use arrow function for the same.
So bellow example using bind in constructor

1. Firstly bind your function inside constructor as below

   this.handlePanel = this.handlePanel.bind(this);
2. Secondly call function inside component as

   handlePanel(){
    // write code here
   }

Comment: Perfect.   `handlePanel = () => {
    this.refs.customPanel._showPanel();
    this.handlePanel = this.handlePanel.bind(this);
  }` then ` key:"Info", icon:"Contact", onClick:this.handlePanel ` within the JSX